# 'pip install watchdog' fails on OS X 10.10.5

Tags: python, macos, watchdog, python-watchdog

pip install watchdog fails with the following error:

```
src/watchdog_fsevents.c:466:33: warning: unused parameter 'self' [-Wunused-parameter]
    watchdog_remove_watch(PyObject *self, PyObject *watch)
                                    ^
    src/watchdog_fsevents.c:491:25: warning: unused parameter 'self' [-Wunused-parameter]
    watchdog_stop(PyObject *self, PyObject *emitter_thread)
                            ^
    src/watchdog_fsevents.c:531:10: warning: missing field 'ml_meth' initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
        {NULL},
             ^
    8 warnings and 2 errors generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/airborne/anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/7c/vvy24k6d483cwl0m6fbl0vdr0000gn/T/pip-build-BozAQp/watchdog/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7c/vvy24k6d483cwl0m6fbl0vdr0000gn/T/pip-nx7ozu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/7c/vvy24k6d483cwl0m6fbl0vdr0000gn/T/pip-build-BozAQp/watchdog/
```

Can anyone please help out with resolving this error ?

Complete error log is here http://pastebin.com/D2qq9tb1

Python version : Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (x86_64)

Solutions suggested in a [previous bug](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/224) raised against OSX 10.9 did not seem to work.

Comment: Not sure but I usually see errors like this when I'm missing a `lib-dev` something or other. Do you know if there are any system dependencies (`python-dev` etc)

Comment: The PyPi page only mentions libYaml and pyYaml. And, I already have Xcode. So, I don't kow what I'm missing.